# auto scaling spins up multiple compute nodes in cfncluster

Tags: amazon-ec2

when I try to run a single job 'hellojob.sh' in the cfncluster multiple compute nodes spun up. It is a very simple job.please find my script below.

hellojob.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
echo "Hello World from $(hostname)"
```

can anyone please tell me how to avoid autoscaling spin up to multiple compute nodes.

please find my config file below:

```
[root@ip-00-00-0-1000 .cfncluster]# cat config
[aws]
aws_region_name = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id = ***************
aws_secret_access_key = *******************

[cluster default]
vpc_settings = testdev-dev
key_name = testdev-developers
initial_queue_size = 0
s3_read_write_resource =*
pre_install = s3://cfncluster/pre_install_script.sh

[vpc testdev-dev]
master_subnet_id = subnet-*****
vpc_id = vpc-*****
additional_sg=sg-*****
vpc_security_group_id =sg-*****
use_public_ips=false


[global]
update_check = true
sanity_check = true
cluster_template = default

[scaling]
scaling_cooldown = 2000
```

Comment: You did not provide any detail regarding your ASG configuration.

Comment: @Putnik i have added my config file. please find the config details above.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by including the scaling_threshold (and optionally scaling_threshold2) parameters in your scaling configuration. The scaling_threshold parameter determines the number of instances to add when an autoscaling ScaleUp event is triggered. See a snippet of my config below as an example

```
## Scaling settings
#[scaling custom]
# Threshold for triggering CloudWatch ScaleUp action
# (defaults to 4 for default template) 
scaling_threshold = 1
# Number of instances to add when called CloudWatch ScaleUp action
# (defaults to 2 for default template) 
scaling_adjustment = 1
# Threshold for triggering CloudWatch ScaleUp2 action
# (defaults to 4 for default template) 
scaling_threshold2 = 10
# Number of instances to add when called CloudWatch ScaleUp2 action
# (defaults to 20 for default template) 
scaling_adjustment2 = 2
```